# What will the following command delete? rm -r * /mnt/folder

Tags: rm

I just want to make sure:

`rm -r * /mnt/folder1`

This deletes folder1 and all files and folders in the directory that I am actually in?

Comment: just to be safe `rm -r ./* /mnt/folder1` the star alone can be dangerous.

Comment: i need to know with the star *

Comment: when you use the star alone it can match everything, with the notation I used it can only match all files inside your current directory.

Comment: Is it a school task?

Comment: lol, it was panic mode and not school task.  I should stop using the * when deleting. I wanted to type rm -r /mnt/folder1/* instead^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command will remove all files and directories from the current directory and will also remove the `/mnt/folder1` directory.

Comment: thank you very much